# Qiskit syntax to remove all gate operations for a given qubit line in a circuit

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate, quantum-circuit

I am looking for a method to remove all operations for a given qubit in a Qiskit circuit. Here, I am looking to remove potentially many gate operations that are operating on that qubit line. Ideally I would want to remove all operations on that qubit line, including delay gates and measurement operations. I can write code to do this using string parsing in OpenQASM, but this does not work for circuits which are defined in Qiskit and not OpenQASM (for example, scheduled circuits which have delay gates), which is why I am wondering if there is a general method built into Qiskit for this operation.

My question is similar to existing questions, such as [this one](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/5144/can-i-remove-gates-from-a-quantumcircuit), but I could not find this exact question posed elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve that is by manipulating the list of instructions in the circuit directly as follows.

Let's first create a sample circuit that contains measurements and delays:

```
from qiskit.circuit.random import random_circuit

circ = random_circuit(4, 10)
circ.delay(1)
circ.measure_all()
```

[image]

Now, remove all instructions for one of the qubits

```
qubit_index = 2
qubit = circ.qbit_argument_conversion(qubit_index)[0]

for idx, _instruction in reversed(list(enumerate(circ.data))):
    for _qubit in _instruction.qubits:
        if _qubit == qubit:
            del circ.data[idx]
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thank you!